# Which are the best free Visual Studio 2008 plugins?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, lint

I am new to Visual Studio 2008 (not 2010). What do you think are the best free Visual Studio 2008 add-ins or plugins? Is it there some LINT one?

Thanks

Comment: This should be a community wiki as it is fairly subjective.

Comment: It is also both very broad (different users have different needs) and specific (one specific IDE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerCommands is pretty nice: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ProjectName=PowerCommands&ReleaseId=559

CodeRush Express helps you quite a lot, and Code Style Enforcer is nice too.

CodeRush: http://devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/CodeRushX/

Code Style Enforcer + DXCore: http://joel.fjorden.se/static.php?page=CodeStyleEnforcer and devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/DXCore/

Answer (score 2):

There is [Visual Lint](http://www.riverblade.co.uk/products/visual_lint/index.html) for example, but it's not free. In my very subjective opinion LINT is not very popular anymore.

Many use [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) for subversion access.

I personally like [PhatStudio](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phatstudio/), because it helps me to browse through my C++ projects quickly.

There's also [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) for creating documentation.

I can also recommend [StyleCop](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis) for .NET projects. It comes with a set of guidelines/rules for code/documentation quality and provides style guides.

The list is pretty extensive, depends on personal preference and cannot ever be complete.

There's even a list on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Microsoft_Visual_Studio_add-ins)  which contains un-free plugins, too.

Microsoft itself has a gallery with plugin/extensions, etc for Visual Studio which can be found [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/).

Comment: +1 for AnkhSVN and GhostDoc (http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Bill Evjen's blog lists a few [visual studio 2008 plug ins](http://geekswithblogs.net/evjen/archive/2008/03/10/120449.aspx) that range from simple and useful.

A good place to start looking would be the [Visual Studio Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/).

Answer (score 0):

a good [Spell Checker](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/7c8341f1-ebac-40c8-92c2-476db8d523ce) helps me out a lot ([here is one for 2008](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/0E8671A4-968D-4247-BB4B-908CA1F0E522), never used it though).

If you are interested in getting in to Text templeting the free version of [tangible T4 Editor](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/60297607-5fd4-4da4-97e1-3715e90c1a23) is pretty nice ([here is the 2008 version](http://www.tangible.de/download/tangible%20modelling%20tools%20with%20T4Editor.zip)).